# Python: How to delete the 2nd and 3rd element/variable for every line of text file

Tags: python

I have a text file with this format:

> ```
> 1   1  (101):  3.7e+08  1.2e+02  5.1234
> 2   1  (101):  3.5e+08  8.2e+02  6.2222
> 2   2  (101):  1.7e+08  2.2e+02  7.4567
> 3   1  (101):  8.7e+08  3.2e+02  9.2123
> ```

I would like to get it into the following format:

> ```
> 1   3.7e+08  1.2e+02  5.1234
> 2   3.5e+08  8.2e+02  6.2222
> 2   1.7e+08  2.2e+02  7.4567
> 3   8.7e+08  3.2e+02  9.2123
> ```

I'm essentially trying to delete the second and third element/variable from each line. Any suggestions? I'm new to python and unsure how approach this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

The code is a work in progress.
So far, it reads file.txt and removes the first three lines and writes it out as newfile.txt. Here it is:

```
import sys
try:
     f=open('file.txt', 'r')
     lines = f.readlines()
except IOError:
     print('File file.txt does not exist')
     sys.exit(1)
for line in lines:
     sys.stdout.write(line)
     f.close()
# Deleting the first three lines
del lines[0:3]
# Deleting the second and third element of every line

f=open('newfile.txt','w')
f.writelines(lines)
print(lines)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I also added Python in the question title

Comment: Do you have any code to share that you have tried writing?  Generally, you will receive more assistance if you post something you have tried that didn't work rather than a general "how do I accomplish X?" question.

Comment: Code has now been added.

Comment: Will the second and third variables always be the same length? In your example, the second is always len=1 and your third is len=6

Comment: for this example the second and third variables are the same length. It would however be preferable to have robustness in the event the length changes. What's your approach in the event the length is fixed?

Comment: If it's fixed, you can simply do `sys.stdout.write(line[:4] + line[15:])` for each line. Adjust the numbers as needed. Obviously this won't work if the substrings are variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe what you are looking for.

```
import sys
try:
     f=open('file.txt', 'r')
     lines = f.readlines()
except IOError:
     print('File file.txt does not exist')
     sys.exit(1)

for line in lines:
     sys.stdout.write(line)
     f.close()

newl=[]
for line in lines:
    temp = line.split()
    newl.append([temp[0]]+temp[3:])

f=open('newfile.txt','w')
f.writelines(['  '.join(l)+'\n' for l in newl])
print(newl)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I get the following: SyntaxError: can't assign, f.writelines([' '.join(1)+'\n' for 1 in new1])

Comment: it is `l` - lowercase `L`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best accomplished by reading the file with `csv`. It appears the file is tab-delimited (please confirm?), so you would do this by

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t') # Adjust delimiter as appropriate to your file format.

    # Skip 3 lines.
    for i in xrange(3):
         reader.next()

    new_lines = []
    for line in reader:
         new_line = [line[0]] + line[3:]
         new_lines.append(new_line)

# Write to the new file
with open('new_file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t') # Again, adjust delimiter as appropriate.
    writer.writerows(new_lines)
```

Comment: I don't believe its tab delimited. Some text is separate by one space and some by more. I did however try your suggestion but I get the following error message:                                                                                      with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax